# Vue.js blur with enter event - triggers both of them

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make it so that when I press enter OR if I lose focus from an element it triggers a function but when I press enter it then triggers the blur event also. So the function is called twice. It should only be called once.

```
<input v-on:blur="saveField('name')" keyup.enter="saveField('name')">
```

The problem is that my saveField() function hides the element, triggering also the blur event.

I guess the other issue is how not to have to write the same function call twice. (DRY).

Comment: hmm why not remove the `enter` event listener?

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce your problem: can you create an MCVE? http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/m1wyar7z/ Also, I think you are missing the `v-on:` in front of the `keyup.enter` binding.

Comment: Oh, I see. My problem is that the function hides the element which triggers the blur after the enter key press

Answer (score 1):

You can use some kind of condition to check if the value needs to be updated. It seems complicated to avoid the two events from being triggered:

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="inputValue" type="text" @blur="save()" @keyup.enter="save()">
  <div v-for="saving in savings">
    {{ saving }}
  </div>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    inputValue: '',
    savedValue: '',
    savings: []
  },
  methods: {
    save () {
        if (this.inputValue !== this.savedValue) {
        this.savings.push('Saving value ' + this.inputValue)
        this.savedValue = this.inputValue
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6kfz48m/